# Github commit to tag for version control

Tags: git, version-control, github

We have a Github repo with a single branch 'master' representing stable versions of our code-base.

I want to be able to commit with 'tags' on specific commits that represent 'version' numbers as I've seen people doing.

We use 'SmartGit' to interact with the system, so when I create a new 'Tag' in the local version, I use 'Push Advanced' to create a new tag on the server.

However, none of the commit notes representing my specific changes to a tag are being displayed, and I'm worried that I'm not correctly committing to a specific '*tag*' and don't want to overwrite the '**master**' branch with a commit of a bugfix in an older version of the code (earlier version).

Anyone done this sort of staggered version control with **tags** in ***Github/SmartGit***

[image: gitup/smartgit with tagging]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to commit with 'tags' on specific commits 
>   none of the commit notes representing my specific changes to a tag are being displayed

You can put a tag on a (one) specific commit, but you cannot make "commits" to a tag.
You correctly push through the advanced options of SmartGit that tag to the remote.

But be wary of what commit SmartGit is able to tag: [according to its documentation](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation.html?page=addTag), it only tags the current commit.
That means you have to checkout said commmit first, before tagging it.

Comment: Think of tags like bookmarks.  They don't *add* any content to the page, they just save a spot, with a label.  If you intend to maintain multiple versions (i.e. backport fixes on master into old versions) you want to use a branch for those versions, not a tag.  Tags should be used to save specific release points ("this is where v1.0.3 was at").

Answer (score 1):

Tags are meant as human readable pointer to some specific version of a project; therefore they are **immutable**.  You cannot create commit "on tag" -- Git won't allow it.

What you can do is to create maintenance ***branch*** for a given tag, and work on that.  For example if you tagged last stable release with `v1.3`, you can create `v1.3.x` branch for maintenance (bugfixes) only; you would create there `v1.3.1` tags etc.